# I want to store SignalR Connection IDs in Redis

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, redis, signalr

I am using Redis Server as SignalR backplane in a .net core SignalR application. Is it ok to create an additional connection to Redis server besides the one maintained by SignalR library?

If Redis Server currently keeps my connection IDs, how I can access?

My configuration

```
            services.AddSignalR(hubOptions =>
            {
               hubOptions.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
            }).AddRedis("127.0.0.1:6379,DefaultDatabase=1");
```